# Create GIT tags inside Bamboo

Tags: git, build, tags, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I am a completely newbie to the Bamboo. I have repositories stored in GIT and STASH. I am using Bamboo for a build. I am facing an issue while creating git tags in Bamboo before build and pushing it to repositories. 
Can anyone guide me in right direction?

Comment: have you tried anything? you should be able to create tags by running the git command: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging
(you will need to add the server ssh key to stash allowed keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at documentation at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/how-to-push-to-repository-under-ssh-protocol-using-script-task-747831642.html.

Outcome, Bamboo checkout repo not from Stash directly but from proxy repository. You need to set remote repository inside Script task and perform required operations there.